# Accessing RasPi GPIO from a Container

Tags: docker, .net-core, raspberry-pi, raspbian, podman

I'm trying to access the Raspberry Pi 4 GPIOs from a .NET Core 3.1 application running inside a Podman container but I keep getting permissions failures.  I'm running the latest Raspbian Buster base OS.

The Dockerfile is straightforward:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1
ADD myapp/* /myapp/
WORKDIR /myapp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

This is my `run` command:

`podman container run --rm --privileged -v /dev:/dev -v /sys:/sys myapp`

I've tried with `--device=/dev/gpiomem` as well.

I still get the following exception from the app:

> [16:49:18 ERR] The type initializer for 'System.Device.Gpio.Drivers.SysFsDriver' threw an exception. InnerException: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/sys/class/gpio/gpiochip504/label' is denied.

Trying to be heavy-handed, I've done a `sudo chmod -R 777 /sys/class/gpio` at the OS level before running the container but that doesn't help.

Any thoughts on how to get the container to have access to the hardware resource?